# Getting authentication error while sending mail with PHPmailer using PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting the following error while sending the email using `PHPMailer`.

> Error:

**SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.**

I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/oditek.in/subhra/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
function SentMail($to,$from,$subject,$msg_body,$reply_to='',$cc='',$files=''){      
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $body = $msg_body;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->Username   = "tuurbus@gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password   = "abcd_bs@123";
    $mail->SetFrom($from,'tuurbus');
    if($reply_to!=''){
        $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_to,'tuurbus');
    }
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
    if(count($files) > 0 && $files!=''){
        for($i=0;$i<=count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $mail->AddAttachment($files[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if($cc!=''){
        $addrcc = explode(',',$cc);
        foreach ($addrcc as $addresscc) {
            $mail->AddCC(trim($addresscc));
        }
    }
    if($mail->Send()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
$to="tuurbus@gmail.com";
$from="subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com";
$subject="Test email";
$msg_body="Hi, This is customize request";
$ret = SentMail($to,$from,$subject,$msg_body);
echo $ret;exit;
?>
```

I have also turned on the the `less secured app` option in gmail but still same error is coming. This is the implementation like `contact us` form in website. User will send the email request to admin(`here tuurbus`). Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I forget but I think there is a setting in gmail you have to change, it was either for `smtp` or `IMAP` I use both and to be honest it's been like 3 years sense I set that up ... lol.

Comment: here it is `It turns out that in order for Google to authorize a third party server to access your account via SMTP now, you have to enable “Less Secure Apps” on your Gmail account. `  source https://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix : I have also turned on and same issue still there.

Comment: SSL and Port `465` as per that post I linked.  I do see `TLS` now same diff as `SSL` just the newer.  Not sure if the port really make a difference, doesn't hurt to try right as you have `587`.  you may want to change your Password, Just saying as its in the question!!!!

Comment: I changed as per you but same issue.

Comment: I don't know then, it's very hard to test it.  I dont see anything obvious.  Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: You’re using an old version of PHPMailer - get the latest from github. You’ve also based your code on an obsolete example. I don’t know why you’re getting suggestions about google when you’re using sendgrid. Set `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server says.

Answer (score -1):

Download Phpmailer package from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ link & copy into your project and extract zip folder into your project and change the your code as following also check your password ,email id. Its works by my side.

```
<?php
include_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
function SentMail($to,$from,$subject,$msg_body,$reply_to='',$cc='',$files=''){      
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $body = $msg_body;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->Username   = "tuurbus@gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Password   = "abcd_bs@123";
    $mail->SetFrom($from,'tuurbus');
    if($reply_to!=''){
        $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_to,'tuurbus');
    }
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
    if(count($files) > 0 && $files!=''){
        for($i=0;$i<=count($files);$i++){
            if(is_file($files[$i])){
                $mail->AddAttachment($files[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if($cc!=''){
        $addrcc = explode(',',$cc);
        foreach ($addrcc as $addresscc) {
            $mail->AddCC(trim($addresscc));
        }
    }
    if($mail->Send()){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
$to="tuurbus@gmail.com";
$from="subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com";
$subject="Test email";
$msg_body="Hi, This is customize request";
$ret = SentMail($to,$from,$subject,$msg_body);
echo $ret;exit;
?>
```

Comment: Its somewhere wrong setting in gmail because I changed some other email id with same code its working fine.

Comment: This code will not work in recent versions of PHPMailer. The right way to load it is to use composer, as the docs describe.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com'); 
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
```